# Code UI String speed

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

i'm using the framework coded ui to develop an interface test of a desktop application. This framework generates a lot of lines of code autogenerated, for example, in order to tip "hello" it uses 5 lines, one for each character.

So in order to avoid this, I extend the class UIMAP and I'm trying to put the string directly but sometimes coded UI writes wrong the string that I pass by parameter (It seems that the writing is too fast)

```
Keyboard.SendKeys(uIQueryClient, "hello", ModifierKeys.None);
```

Do you know how can I fix it?

Comment: I have never encountered such issue, but if calling the method for each key separately doest the job, why not to write a custom method which takes a string and then calls SendKeys for each char separately? Same clean and works.
On the other hand, in most cases with coded UI you could go around using Keyboard directly, just telling inputs to get filled with data. At least for the web, never tried desktop.

Answer (score 0):

When you create an UIMap (let's say *TestMap*.uitest) you will notice that it creates a partial class definition in the *TestMap*.cs file. My suggestion would be to rewrite that method in the partial class file (an delete the original from the UIMap) and not use *Keyboard.SendKeys*. Instead, set the *Text* property of the control:

```
    public void FillText(string text)
    {
       this.UIPanel.UIParentControl.UITextBox.Text = text;
    }
```

You say that it writes the string very fast, however I have found SendKeys to be very slow when you specify the control on which to send the keys.